# MSSQL script to populate values in range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get from the following table
start   end
1   999
1000    9999
10000   99999

The result should be

values
1
2
3
.
.
.
99999**

Thank you

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use table number for join

```
SELECT 
  b.Value
FROM <T> a
INNER JOIN 
     <Tables number 1...1000000> b
ON
 b.Value BETWEEN a.Start AND a.end
```

Comment: correct answer, but I think you'd help him more if you presented a tables number implementation ready